# .NET Interactive - how to change collection output size

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, dotnet-interactive, .net-interactive

I'm using .NET Interactive notebook inside VS Code and want to change the number of printed out elements:

```cs
var x = Enumerable.Range(0,21);
x.Display();
```

Only first 20 element are shown in the the output:

[image]

Can I somehow increase the size of output?

Comment: if you change 0 to 1 you will see it works fine, but with 0 it does not takes the last one, for me is also question why?!

Comment: @HadiR. `var x = Enumerable.Range(1,21)` still results for me in only 20 elements being printed. Just the last printed one is changed from 19 to 20 (while the actual last one is 21).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Formatter` from `Microsoft.DotNet.Interactive.Formatting` namespace to change the size of the output:

```cs
using Microsoft.DotNet.Interactive.Formatting; 
Formatter.ListExpansionLimit = 25;
```

[Docs](https://github.com/dotnet/interactive/blob/main/docs/formatting.md#user-configuration-of-default-formatters):

- `Formatter.ListExpansionLimit` = 20

  Gets or sets the limit to the number of items that will be written out in detail from an `IEnumerable` sequence.
- `Formatter<T>.ListExpansionLimit` = (not set)

  An optional type-specific list expansion limit